# Wrong onChange event validation in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems pretty staightforward, but my validation in React component does not work as expected. Obviously, it should pass only integers from 1 to 10, but any input including range numbers triggers `else` section of `handleInput` method:

```
class FormToRefresh extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {value: 1}
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
  } 

  handleInput(e) {
    let input = e.target.value
    const inputRange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    if(inputRange.includes(input)) {
      this.setState({value: input}) 
    }
    else {
      alert("Wrong input")
      this.setState({value: this.state.value})  
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>            

      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.value} 
        onChange={this.handleInput} 
      />

      <button type="submit">
        Refresh
      </button>

      </form>
    </div>        

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
const inputRange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
if(inputRange.includes(input))
```

Your array in numbers, but `e.target.value` will be a string since it's the content of an input box. Try this:

```
const inputRange = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
if(inputRange.includes(parseInt(input)))
```

Should convert the input to an integer first. And remember to do error handling

Answer (score 2):

`value` field on `input` node returns value in `String`

So, try to parse string to number:

```
let input = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
```